# Jquery/C# to convert string/text into asterisk.

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Let say i have this MVC model that pass IC numbers "S1234567G" into model.Ic

I want to use Jquery or C# mvc controller to set that only certain roles are able to see this IC numbers. if it is other roles like staffs, employees they can only see those number in "*********".

Consider that I do not want any of the IC numbers to show even if they Press F12 code inspector - they are unable to see those numbers unless their role is Administrator.

Comment: Create a get and check here the role before getting the value ? ..

Answer (score 1):

With asp.net identity framework :

http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-aspnet-identity

You can do something like this :

```
@if (Request.IsAuthenticated && User.IsInRole("Admin"))
{
  <span>S1234567G</span>
}
else
{
  <span>*******</span>
}
```

If the user is not an admin he can't see the span even with f12.